# Is there a way to convert a rbxl file to an exe file so I can execute it without needing robloxplayerlauncher.exe

Tags: roblox

I need to convert an rbxl file easily to an exe file or any file that i can run on windows without needing another file

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

The [rbxl file format](http://www.classy-studios.com/Downloads/RobloxFileSpec.pdf) is a compressed version of a Roblox place.
And just like any other specialized file format, it cannot do anything without the right application.